# Interval schedule maximization when encountering intervals with equivalent end points

Tags: algorithms, optimization, scheduling

In interval scheduling, the ***greedy solution*** which *maximizes* the schedule that contains the largest number of *"compliant intervals"* involves initially sorting the list of intervals in ascending order by the end-times/point of each interval.

What confuses me, is if two or more intervals have the same ending time.

When performing the **initial sort**, should one base the sort of the sub-range of intervals on start time?

and if so should it be in ascending or descending order?

Comment: If two intervals have the same ending time, you can sort them however you like; you'll get the same answer both ways (the proof that the greedy solution works makes this clear).

Answer (score 1):

The greedy algorithm can be characterized as follows:

Let $I$ be the initial set of intervals

1) Select an interval, $x \in I$, with the earliest finishing time.

2) Remove $x$ and all intervals intersecting $x$ from $I$, obtaining $I^{'}$.

3) add $x$ to the solution

4) Set $I=I^{'}$

5) Continue until $I$ is empty.

Here, $x$ is some remaining interval that finishes before all other intervals in $I$. When we add $x$ to our solution we have already removed any interval with the same finish time as $x$ that may have had a start time which was "too early." If there is some other $y\in I$ with the same finish time as $x$ that is present when $x$ is chosen, then by necessity, both $x$ and $y$ begin after the last interval we added to our solution, so either is a legitimate choice.

Comment: Can I suggest changing "Select the interval" to "Select an interval"? I would also emphasise that the state (the *number* of selected-so-far intervals, and the *set* of remaining intervals) will be identical after choosing any  interval having minimum end time.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I will happily apply that edit. Nice catch.